# MongoDB Find/Get Last Item w/ Parent Name and Object Array Value

Tags: mongodb

```
Schema({
  name: String,
  items: [{
    body: String,
    active: Boolean,
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    added: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }],
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

I want to get the last item in 'items' with a 'name' where 'items.active' is true.

Tried many different configurations.. this is basically what i want to do:

```
List.find({ name: LIST_NAME, 'items.active': true }, { items: { $slice: -1 } }, function(err, result){...do stuff w/ result.body...});
```

Appreciate any help, thx.

Comment: Do you intend to get the latest `item` - sorted by `Date`? or just the last `item` in the `items` array?

Answer (score 0):

Using [Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) was ultimately the solution:

```
  List.aggregate(
    { $match: { name: req.params.list }},
    { $unwind: '$items' },
    { $match: { 'items.active': true }},
    { $sort: { 'items.added': -1 }},
    { $limit: 1 }, function (err, result) {
      if(err) {
        res.status(500);
        res.send(err);

      } else {
        console.log(result);
        res.send(result[0].items.body);
      }
  });
```